# Within a M365 Tenant, Is There a Setting to Disable All Tips Globally Once and for All?

Tags: office365, user-interface, global

With Microsoft 365 tenants, tips just keep popping up everywhere, all the time, through apps (web and desktop versions) and all the admin centres. This is especially crazy with a new account: the first few days are hellish, the user is subject to a barrage of useless tips. It has to stop.

My users are sick of them. I know that a user can disable tips individually, but I want to help all of my users all at once.

Is there a global settings on the tenant to disable all tips?